# Find a number of a given number of digits between given separators

Tags: java, regex

What `regex/pattern` can I use to find the following pattern in a string?

```
#nnnn:
```

`nnnn` can be any 4-digit long number as long as it is sorrounded by a hashtag and a colon.

I have tried the code below:

```java
String string = "#8226:";
if(string.matches( ".*\\d:.*" )) {
  System.out.println( "Yes" );
}
```

It DOES work, but it matches other strings like below:

```java
"This is a string 1234: Hahaha!" // Outputs "Yes"
"Hello 1834: World!!!"           // Outputs "Yes"
```

I want it to only match the pattern at the top of the question.

Can anybody tell me where did I go wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: You can use: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: Regular expressions might help

Comment: String strWithNumber = "&#amp;#8226:

Comment: if(strWithNumber.matches(".*\\d:.*")){
  System.out.println("Yes");
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done with Regular Expression

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class FindPattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#[0-9]{4}:");

        String text = "#1233:#3433:abc#3993: #a343:___#8888:ki";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }

    }
}
```

output is:

```
#1233:
#3433:
#3993:
#8888:
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already a pattern: `#nnnn:`. The only problem is that this is not a java compatible regular expression. Let's convert.

`#` and `:` are valid character literals, so let these untouched.

As you probably know (according to your solution), a number is denoted with the `\d` sequence (note, there are some alternatives, e. g. `[0-9]`, `\p{Digit}`). Just replace all `n`s with `\d`:

```
#\d\d\d\d:
```

There are four equal subpatterns here, so we can shorten it with a fixed quantifier:

```
#\d{4}:
```

You can now write `string.matches("#\\d{4}:")`. Note that this is slow because compiles the given regex pattern every time. If this code is called frequently, I would consider using a precompiled `Pattern` like:

```java
Pattern HASH_NUMBER_COLON_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("#\\d{4}:");
// ...
if (HASH_NUMBER_COLON_PATTERN.matcher(yourString).matches()) {
    // ...
}
```

Even better to use some regular expression builder library, such as [regex-builder](https://github.com/sgreben/regex-builder), [JavaVerbalExpressions](https://github.com/VerbalExpressions/JavaVerbalExpressions) or [RegexBee](https://github.com/davidsusu/regexbee). These tools can make your intention very clear. RegexBee example:

```java
Pattern HASH_NUMBER_COLON_PATTERN = Bee
        .then(Bee.fixedChar('#'))
        .then(Bee.intBetween(1000, 9999))
        .then(Bee.fixedChar(':'))
        .toPattern()
```